# ¿Como limitar los valores de una propiedad de un objeto en JS?

Tags: javascript

A la hora de crear un objeto el campo especialidad solo puede tener los valores 1, 2 o 3 como puedo limitarlo?

```js
function Sandskill(nom, edad, especialidad, comp){
    this.nombre = nom;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.especialidad = especialidad;
    this.comp = comp;

    this.nombreCompleto = function(){
        return this.nombre +" "+this.apellido;
    }
}

var s1 = new Sandskill ("e", "e", "1", "e");
```

Comment: a la hora de introducirlo, validar el valor con una condición.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer dos cosas: por un lado, añadir la comprobación en el constructor, y por el otro, evitar que pueda modificar el parámetro posteriormente con valores no válidos. He reescrito tu definición de objeto usando la sintaxis de clases, por sencillez:

```js
class Sandskill{
  constructor(nom, edad, especialidad, comp){
    this.nombre = nom;
    this.edad = edad;
    if(especialidad == 1 || especialidad == 2 || especialidad == 3){
      this._especialidad = especialidad;
    }else{
      throw new Error('Especialidad no válida');
    }
    this.comp = comp;

    this.nombreCompleto = function(){
        return this.nombre +" "+this.apellido;
    }
  }
  
  set especialidad(valor) {
     if(valor == 1 || valor == 2 || valor == 3){
       this._especialidad = valor;
     }
  }
  get especialidad() {
    return this._especialidad;
  }
}

var s1 = new Sandskill ("e", "e", "2", "e");
s1.especialidad=4; //será ignorado
console.log(s1.especialidad);
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que con una condición la cual valide el valor de `especialidad` es suficiente, algo así:

```js
function Sandskill(nom, edad, especialidad, comp){
    this.nombre = nom;
    this.edad = edad;
    if(especialidad == 1 || especialidad == 2 || especialidad == 3){
      this.especialidad = especialidad;
    }else{
      this.especialidad = null;
    }
    this.comp = comp;

    this.nombreCompleto = function(){
        return this.nombre +" "+this.apellido;
    }
}

var s1 = new Sandskill ("e", "e", "1", "e");
```

Comment: Posiblemente, si el campo especialidad necesariamente tiene que ser 1, 2 o 3, el valor null tampoco sea admisible. Tal vez sea mejor asumir 1, aplicando la función módulo

Comment: @amenadiel tienes razón, pero lo importante es que el OP entienda la lógica que se está implementando el cambiar un valor por defecto es lo de menos, gracias! :D

Comment: Cierto, la validación es correcta, sólo era un comentario al margen.

Answer (score 1):

Limpio:

```js
function Sandskill(nom, edad, especialidad, comp){
    this.nombre = nom;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.especialidad = especialidad > 0 && especialidad < 4 ?
                        `válida y es la número ${especialidad}` :
                        "inválida";
    this.comp = comp;
    this.show = () => this.especialidad;
}

 var s1 = new Sandskill ("e", "e", "1", "e");
 console.log(`La especialidad es ${s1.show()}`);
```